# Changing label based on current time

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I've got a problem where my label won't update with the time.
It's supposed to change number at certain time intervals eg. when it's 7:30 am - 8:15 am it's supposed to change label text to "1".

Here's the piece of code responsible for this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Hour = DateTime.Now.Hour();
    int Minute = DateTime.Now.Minute();
    if (Hour >= 6 && Minute >= 40 && Hour <= 7 && Minute <= 25)
    {
        label5.Text = "0";
    }
    else if (Hour >= 7 && Minute >= 30 && Hour <= 8 && Minute <= 15)
    {
        label5.Text = "1";
    }
    else if (Hour >= 8 && Minute >= 20 && Hour <= 9 && Minute <= 5)
    {
        label5.Text = "2";
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "nothing";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to rethink your logic a bit - the hour and minute comparisons need to be done in pairs.  Right now for example you're asking for `Minute` to match both `>= 30` _and_ `<= 15` for that condition to match without taking into account what the hour is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your conditions are set so that they can never be true: minutes can never be greater than 40 AND less than 25.

To fix your code as is, you need to group your conditions so you're comparing pairs of hours and minutes, where the pairs are evaluated first:

```
if ((Hour >= 6 && Minute >= 40) && (Hour <= 7 && Minute <= 25))
```

---

However you might consider using the `TimeSpan.Parse` method (or the `DateTime.Parse` method along with the `TimeOfDay` property) to compare times, sort of like the following, which I think is more readable.

I've mixed the use of `TimeSpan.Parse` and `DateTime.Parse` so you can see how they differ. You should just pick one or the other (although it's important to note that AM/PM is a US culture thing. If you plan on using this in other cultures, then the `TimeSpan` method + 24-hour time is preferred):

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (currentTime >= DateTime.Parse("6:40 AM").TimeOfDay &&
        currentTime <= DateTime.Parse("7:25 AM").TimeOfDay)
    {
        label5.Text = "0";
    }
    else if (currentTime >= TimeSpan.Parse("07:30") &&
             currentTime <= TimeSpan.Parse("08:15"))
    {
        label5.Text = "1";
    }
    else if (currentTime >= TimeSpan.Parse("08:20") &&
             currentTime <= TimeSpan.Parse("09:05"))
    {
        label5.Text = "2";
    }
    else
    {
        label5.Text = "nothing";
    }
}
```

Note that if you use `TimeSpan.Parse`, you have to use 24-hour time. So `"2:00 PM"` would be represented as `"14:00"`. If you don't like this then use the `DateTime.Parse`, followed by a call to the `TimeOfDay` property:

```
// Instead of this
if (currentTime >= TimeSpan.Parse("18:40")

// You could write this
if (currentTime >= DateTime.Parse("6:40 PM").TimeOfDay)
```

Comment: I'm still wondering how I made such a stupid mistake with the minutes variable :P
Good to know that you can parse time so easily like this.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: If you're relatively new to programming, it's very common to forget parenthesis or mix up `&&` with `||`. Not stupid, just a stepping stone on the path... :)

Comment: Going with DateTime.Parse can be tricky, Unless you specify a CultureInfo, it depends on current settings. Much easier IMO use the `TimeSpan` ctor accepting hours, minutes and second: `DateTime.Parse("6:40 PM")` becomes `new DateTime(18, 40, 0)` (and it works always, it does not depends on regional settings)

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are always false, take this one for instance:

```
if (Hour >= 6 && Minute >= 40 && Hour <= 7 && Minute <= 25)
```

`Minute >= 40 && Minute <= 25` will always be false as one of them can be true at a time.
I think you are looking for something like:

```
if ((Hour = 6 && Minute >= 40) || (Hour = 7 && Minute <= 25))
```